# Add a full-row swipe action using native UITableViewRowAction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

Is there any native iOS functionality for UITableViews that allows you to implement a full left or right swipe action on a cell?

There is obviously [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2153-how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1-2) to do this, [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell), and I think [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) can do this too, but I'd prefer to do this natively if possible using `UITableViewRowAction`.

Here's (shamelessly copying) a gif of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]
<sub>(source: [raywenderlich.com](https://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Cues250.gif))</sub>